# Git: get the list of branches into which current branch was ever merged

Tags: git, version-control, branch

Maybe each developer faced that uncomfortable moment when you don't remember whether you've merged you story code. So you looking for that code and find it's in `my-feature` branch. But you still don't remember whether you merged it or not.

**Question:** *How to get a list of branches into which `my-feature` was merged?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the following command?

```
git branch -a --merged my-feature
```

It will print a list of all branches (local or remote) whose tips are reachable from (i.e. ancestors of) the tip of `my-feature`. If you're only interested in local branches only, you can want drop the `-a` option.

As an example, if your repository looks as follows

```
A -- B [branch1]
      \
       C -- D -- E [origin/HEAD=origin/branch2]
        \         \
         \         H -- I [HEAD=branch4]
          \
           F -- G [branch3]
```

Running

```
git branch -a --merged branch4
```

will print

```
* branch4
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/branch2
remotes/origin/branch2
branch1
```

- Why `branch4`? Because `branch4` is trivially reachable from itself.
- Why `remotes/origin/HEAD` and `remotes/origin/branch2`? Because they both point (indirectly and directly, respectively) to commit `E`, which is an ancestor of `branch4`'s tip, commit `I`.
- Why `branch1`? Because it points to commit `B`, which is an ancestor of commit `I`.
- Why not `branch3`? Because it points to commit `G`, which is *not* an ancestor of commit `I`.